# Use of Turbo Assembler

Tags: assembly, dos, tasm

I use an **IBM** processor, and I have barely begun to delve into **x86** assembly. Now that I have thoroughly read through an assembly book, I decided to put a simple program to the test (one that prints an exclamation mark on the screen):

```
.MODEL SMALL
.CODE
     MOV AH,2h
     MOV DL,21h
     INT 21h
     INT 20h
END
```

Now, there was a similar example in the book titled *Peter Norton's Assembly Language Book for the IBM PC* that went along these lines:

```
.MODEL SMALL
.CODE
     MOV AH,2h
     MOV DL,2Ah
     INT 21h
     INT 20h
END
```

I assume that this program would print an asterisk according to the ASCII table, but I cannot test that because of the fact that I know not how to handle TASM since I barely installed it on my Dell Inspiron which contains an Intel processor (which should imply an IBM system). In the command prompt of the TASM, I typed the following lines of code ultimately in order to assemble the program that I called EXCLAMAT.asm and run it:

```
C:\TASM>TASM EXCLAMAT.asm;
C:\TASM>TLINK EXCLAMAT;
C:\TASM>TD EXCLAMAT.exe
```

When I ran this program, a dialog told me that: "Program has no symbol table"

What did I do incorrectly? Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm curious what is this for? Learning assembly language has a great benefit but why use TASM today?

Comment: _"I use an IBM processor"_. You mean a CPU based on the POWER-architecture? Or are you talking about an IBM PC compatible computer? I don't think that term's been used much in the last 20 years, since IBM's heydays in the PC business are long gone ;)

Comment: Michael: IBM has brought out Cyrix developed 686 CPU's under its own name. Though that is also already quite some time ago. I agree with the general sentiment though, OP drop the 16-bit toolchains asap, and switch to something (at least) 32-bit protected mode. You will get into trouble running those tools as soon as you switch to a 64-bit windows

Answer (score 5):

TD (Turbo Debugger) is the wrong tool to run the program. You need only to type in the program name on the prompt:

```
C:\TASM>EXCLAMAT.exe
```

The message of TD "Program has no symbol table" is just a warning that you see the pure code and no labels or names. To avoid it: `TLINK /v EXCLAMAT;`

Comment: Actually, `TD` would the the right tool to dive into the program execution, for example for step by step execution to grasp the processor instructions execution or track a bug. But indeed to just execute the program, the OP just need to type the program name followed by the return key.

Answer (score 3):

Don't you get some warnings when linking your assembled code? There are several issues when I test it:

- you need to define the program entry point by setting a label at begining of code, then using the directive `end label_defined`, else you get this link error

  > Fatal: No program entry point
- when producing a .exe you need also to allocate a stack with the `.stack` directive else you will have this warning:

  > Warning: No stack
- the `int 20h` was commonly used to terminate a .com program but it is not adapted to .exe. The prefered method is to call the `int 21h` with `AH = 4c` to terminate and specify a return code. See [this MSDN entry](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/72848/en-us) for a detailed explanation.

Thus to compile an behave correctly your program becomes:

```
;produce a .exe file
; tasm exclamat.asm;
; tlink /v exclamat  (/v for including debug info for td)

.model small
.stack          ;if no value given, defaults to 1024

.code
entrypoint:

    mov ah,2h
    mov dl,21h
    int 21h
    
    ; terminate with int 21h / ah=4c instead of int 20h
    ; see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/72848/en-us
    mov ax,4c00h
    int 21h

end entrypoint  ;define the entry point to the specified label
```

In the case you would produce a .com file, there is some other needs:

- assembly must start at the `100h` address
- do not specify a stack
- you can terminate with `int 20h`
- link with the `/t` parameter

Here is the same program modified:

```
;produce a .com file
; tasm exclamat.asm;
; tlink /t exclamat.obj

.model small

.code
    org 100h

entrypoint:
    mov ah,2h
    mov dl,21h
    int 21h
    int 20h
end entrypoint
```

BTW, this codes were tested on a WXP host and the old `tasm.exe` seems to have problems with underlying `ntvdm` process that supports the 16bit legacy code. If your console becomes weird (e.g completion do not work anymore), you might have to kill `ntvdm` to unlock it. I guess you would get a better behavior inside a dos emulator like DOSBox...